# Recover data after the update in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database

I ran some bad code on my site which made all the usernames change to the exact same username  (ratik513) which was the most recently added username.

```
$query2 = "UPDATE users SET username='$'"; mysql_query($query);
```

I don't want any answers concerning what is wrong with this piece of code, I just want to know how to get those usernames back... If it is possible.

Comment: I think restoring from backup is your only option for that.

Comment: If you've arranged things well in advance, this would be possible using point-in-time recovery: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html However, the chances of you having been well-enough prepared for this seem slim-to-vanishing. You're probably just going to have to restore from your most recent backup, or at least restore the most recent backup somewhere else and update matching records by ID, if you want to keep as much data as possible. (My commiserations. An erstwhile colleague once accidentally named all the customers "Shirley" on the live database...)

Comment: off-topic, but still: using `PDO::beginTransaction` allows you to call `PDO::rollBack` before committing a transaction that results in data-loss. Don't use deprecated extensions like `mysql_*`, please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just want to know how to get those usernames back... If it is possible.

If you have a backup file of your db then you can get the data from that using the restore option of your database else you cant get your data back.

Something like:

```
SET autocommit = 0;

START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE ...;
```

Comment: If only a non-deprecated extension that supported transactions existed... like the old `mysql_*`, but _improved_... as in `mysqli_*` :-P

Comment: Yes I contacted my web hosting company and asked them if they had a backup file for my MySQL databases, they had one that worked, unfortunately some of the more recent users usernames remained gone. But it worked out pretty well anyways. And thank you about the advice to use TRANSACTION, I will definately use it next time.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, possible. 
1. If original username was shorter than ratik513 then Innodb marks the old version of the record as deleted and inserts a new one. 
2. Old username along with the PK goes to the undo buffer